# How does react-redux know what store fragment to pass?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm working on my first *react-redux* app. And I'm wondering how does a *reducer* method know which store fragment should be passed for a given action.

Basically my approach is based on two screens: a *list* and a *form*. When I choose an item from a table and click *edit button*, then ENTERPRISE_SELECTED action is dispatched. And the *form* renders that selected item.

This is my store fragment so far:

```
// store skeleton draft
const storeReference = {
  enterprises: {
    filters: [
      { country: null },
      { type: null },
    ],
    list: [{}, {}, {}],
    selected: {} /* object or int. Not yet decided that. */
  }
}
```

Having two different pages (*list* and *form*) I have two different containers:

List defines this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (store, ownProps) => {     
    return {     
        enterprises: store.enterprises.list
    }
}
```

Form defines this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (store, ownProps) => {  
    return {
        data: store.enterprises.selected
    }
}
```

My reducers are basically in a single file. But ENTERPRISE_LIST_SUCCESS receives my root element (so I have to access "list" by myself) while SAVE_ENTERPRISE receives only the "selected" fragment of my store. Why is that?

```
function enterprises (state = {}, action) {

    switch (action.type) {  
        case 'ENTERPRISE_LIST_SUCCESS':   
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                list: action.payload.list
            });  
        case 'ENTERPRISE_SELECTED':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                selected: action.payload.data
            }); 
        case 'ENTERPRISE_UNSELECTED':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                selected: {}
            }); 
        case 'ADD_ENTERPRISE':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                list: state.list.concat([action.payload.data])
            });
        case 'SAVE_ENTERPRISE':
            console.log(state); // Here I don't have list, just selected
            // replace item in list
            const updatedList = state.list.map(item => {

                if(item.id === action.data.id){
                    return { ...item, ...action.payload.data }
                }
                return item
            })

            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                list: updatedList
            });
        case 'REMOVE_ENTERPRISE':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                list: state.list.filter( (item) => { return item.id !== action.payload.id } )
            });  
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default enterprises
```

---

**UPDATED** the reducer with the fix that @DonovanM pointed out.

Notice the problem persists: when I save the form, my SAVE_ENTERPRISE reducer just get `{ selected: {...} }` when I'd expect this:

```
{ 
   list: [...],
   selected: {...}
}
```

That's why I'm asking: shouldn't all the reducers receive the same state? Why this one is missing a chunk? But I'm realizing that somewhere in the middle when I go from list to form that chunk is being erased. Not sure why yet. But that kinda solves the mystery. It's not that I'm receiving something different, I'm just loosing something on the way.

Comment: It looks like you're overwriting your state when you receive `ENTERPRISE_LIST_SUCCESS` because you aren't including `state` in your `Object.assign` statement. Where in the state would you prefer the list to go for that action?

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Nice catch. Thanks. Anyway, question still remains: how does redux knows which fragment should be passed to a reducer?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Reducers receive actions, not fragments. Reducers have access to the previous state via argument, and connect passes that state to your components. and to make things full circle, components dispatch actions

Comment: What you have now is a single reducer that "listens" for 6 different actions. The data basically goes where you tell it to. For instance, when you receive the `ADD_ENTERPRISE` action you're modifying just the `list` part of the store in your `Object.assign` statement so that the value of `action.payload.data` will be added to the `list` array.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. So, I'm always receiving the "correct" state. the one I declared for my reducer in createStore() or combineReducers(). I was just confused because I was receiving just a fragment in SAVE_ENTERPRISE , missing the enterprises list (actually that problem persists but now i know it must have to do with something else).

Comment: I understand now. When you `dispatch` your `SAVE_ENTERPRISE` action you must include whatever data you want to store for that action. Your action would be something like `{ type: 'SAVE_ENTERPRISE', data: { id: list.id }, payload: list }`.

Answer (score 1):

In the reducer you can define on which property to workout your action.
Look at example from redux documentation.
Below you can see that action `SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER` works on `state` when instead action `TOGGLE_TODO` works on a property of `state.todos`.

```
function todoApp(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER:
      // working on `state`
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        visibilityFilter: action.filter
      })
    case TOGGLE_TODO:
      // working on `todos` on `state`
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        todos: state.todos.map((todo, index) => {
          if (index === action.index) {
            return Object.assign({}, todo, {
              completed: !todo.completed
            })
          }
          return todo
        })
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I can see that. And today it's clear for me. Thanks. So, my problem has to do with something else. I'm missing part of my state somewhere. I'm debugging now to see what I discover.

Comment: @mayid thanks for your comment, if you think my answer helped you out, please do not forget to accept my answer :)